# Dataflow DatastoreIO "too much contention" exception handling

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I need to insert a billion or so entities of varying types into Datastore. I'm using a Dataflow to do this. These rows represent complex indexes of other Entities and as such use those Entities as ancestors. I got about 10% through the pipeline when I got 5 "too much contention on these datastore entities" errors and the pipeline crashed.

What strategy should I employ to manage this so that I can get my data inserted without crashing which requires starting the pipeline over?

One thought is to have DatastoreIO put the Entity in question on the back of the queue rather than crashing.

Comment: Datastore does not support high qps writes for a single entity or entity group. You will have to design your application around it. There is some documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scalability)

Answer (score 1):

Datastore does not support high qps writes for a single entity or entity group. You will have to design your application around it. Please see the documentation around [contention](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention) and [scalability](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scalability).

A few key points:

- Avoid lexicographically close keys with high qps
- Shard entities with high write qps